# Low rank function decomposition — necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-rank, function-and-relation-composition, jacobian

Given a function ${\bf f} (x,y,z) = (f_1, \dots, f_n) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^n$, suppose I can write ${\bf f} (x,y,z) = ({\bf g} \circ p)(x,y,z)$ where $p(x,y,z) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ and ${\bf g}(t)=(g_1, \dots, g_n) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf g}, p$ are "sufficiently nice". Then the Jacobian of $\bf f$, which is denoted by ${\bf J}_{{\bf f}}$, is rank-$1$ everywhere, since

$$  \mathbf{J}_{{\bf f}} (x,y,z) =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{d{\bf g}_1}{dt} \\
    \frac{d {\bf g}_2}{d t} \\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{d {\bf g}_n}{d t}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial  p}{\partial x} \\
    \frac{\partial  p}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial  p}{\partial z}
    \end{bmatrix}^\top$$

Is the converse true? i.e. if the Jacobian $\mathbf{J}_{{\bf f}}$ is rank-$1$ everywhere, then does there always exist a decomposition ${\bf f} = {\bf g} \circ p$ as above? I am ok if we need to make mild assumptions on the functions ${\bf f}, {\bf g}, p$. I am not looking for pathological examples.

One idea I had was to use [facts about constant rank maps between manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(differential_topology)#Constant_rank_maps) but I couldn't figure this out...

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I don't need the partial. I also switched the transpose (somehow I thought I made a row vector, not a column vector...)

Comment: I would just use ${\bf g}_i'$